# Using COUNTIFS for a series of values at once

Tags: excel, count, indexing, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Working a step higher then COUNTIFS, I appose a challenge to write a formula without VBA code. The basic data is combined from 1000s of rows with:

- Column A: rows with values from 1 to 3
- Column B: rows with values from 1 to 250.

For this purpose lets say, we are looking at all cells of value "1" in column A, that suit value "5" in column B. To find all matches, we'd use COUNTIFS command.

```
1   1
2   5
1   5
1   7
1   10
3   45
2   12
1   2
2   1

=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;5)
```

The answer here is 1.

Next thing, the "5" in column B belongs to a group, e.g. group from 1 to 9. What would the best way be, to count all the matches in this example, so that for all "1"'s in column A, we'd have to find all matches with values from 1 to 9 in column B?! In the upper example that would result in "4". The obvious solution is with a series of IF commands, but that's unefficient and it easy to make a mistake, that get's easily overseen.

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;"<="&9)
```

Works only as the upper limit. If I give the third criteria range and condition as ">="&1 it does not work - returns 0.

Gasper

Comment: I don't understand why you think COUNTIFS wouldn't work for this as you can specify multiple ranges and conditions? I think you need to show an example of your data as it is unclear from the question.

Comment: I edited a bit. Hope it makes it more clear now

Comment: can you give a table of your **expected results**? i dont clearly understand what you are trying to do? what is the expected column you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the data is in A1:B9, using a lookup table in D1:E10 with letters A-J in column D and numbers 0 to 9 in column E and the following formula in B11 referencing letters entered in A11 and A12:

=COUNTIFS(A1:A9,1,B1:B9,">="&VLOOKUP(A11,$D$1:$E$10,2,FALSE),B1:B9,"<="&VLOOKUP(A12,$D$1:$E$10,2,FALSE))

works, changing the letters in A11 and A12 gives the correct count according to what they correspond to in the looku in D1:E10.

Comment: It works, I finally realized my problems is somewhere else. The problems is, that my second criteria range is not recognized as numbers in cells (picture below). If you look at the formula - this is the N column. Is it even possible to convert the text into a number within one formula? e.g. NUMBERVALUE ?

http://shrani.si/f/1C/Kx/mAYK9Wz/textnumber.jpg

Comment: A little late on my part and sure you've probably figured it out for yourself by now but I think excel's VALUE () function will convert numbers stored as text back to numbers. You can also use TRIM () to remove any whitespace. Alternatively save your data as a CSV file prior to bringing back into excel and assuming no whitespace all numbers will be stored as numbers. The CSV thing is often useful for taking any formatting out of spreadsheets, also removes protection and any formulas.

Answer (score 1):

When you say give third criteria range do you mean:

=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;"<="&9,B1:B9;">=1")

If so then try:

=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;AND("<="&9,;">=1"))

ie have two conditional ranges with the second range having both conditions combined with AND()

Comment: Thnks. But it doesn't always work. Look at the comment

Comment: Not at my pc so can't test this at present but fairly certain that you need to combine both conditions on B with AND()  so you are just testing B once but for a range of values, your lookup should then work

Comment: Your comments are much appreciated. But it doesn't work. I posted the entire formula.. in this case, VLOOKUP offers the upper and lower limit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want(ed) is:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;1;B:B;">=1";B:B;"<=9")
```

Answer (score -1):

Almost there. I noticed that three criteria ranges and conditions work only if I use "=" sign in a condition. As soon as I use

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;"<="&9,B1:B9;">=1")
```

it returns 0. My goal is to eventualy replace the number in a condition with a VLOOKUP command, so the final equation should be smth like

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;"<="&VLOOKUP(...),B1:B9;">=VLOOKUP(...)")
```

But the "<" and ">" signs mess with this. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is my entire line, if it offers any further indication. The AND() commands is at the end - and it still results in 0

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("baza!$";SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH("card_type_id";baza!$A$1:$AAA$1;0);4);"1";"");"$2:$";SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH("card_type_id";baza!$A$1:$AAA$1;0);4);"1";"");"$15000"));IF(C6="računska";1;0);INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("baza!$";SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(IF($C$4="CC_SI_klasifikacija";"building_classification_id";0);baza!$A$1:$AAA$1;0);4);"1";"");"$2:$";SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(IF($C$4="CC_SI_klasifikacija";"building_classification_id";0);baza!$A$1:$AAA$1;0);4);"1";"");"$15000"));AND("<="&VLOOKUP($C$5;$K$203:$N$223;4;FALSE);">="&VLOOKUP($C$5;$K$203:$N$223;3;FALSE)))
```